# Access data fields outside of export default - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was wondering if it is possible to access the data that is within the `export default` in my javascript file for my Vue component. I am trying to get the contents of the `routes` array inside the `calculateAndDisplayRoute()` function.

**overview.js**

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var origin, dest;
  for (var route in this.routes /*<--HERE*/) {
    console.log('www')
    if(route.id == this.filter){
      console.log('true')
    }
  }
  directionsService.route({
    origin: 'Vancouver',
    destination: 'Chicago',
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'fleet-overview',
  data () {
    return {
      view: '',
      routes: [], //<--HERE
      users: [],
      errorRoute: '',
      response: [],
      filter: 'searchby',
      searchTerm: '',
      users: [],

    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.routeView();
  },
  methods: {
      initMap: function(){
        this.$nextTick(function(){
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 45.49, lng: -73.61},
            zoom: 9
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          var onChangeHandler = function() {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
          };
          document.getElementById('filterselect').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        })
      }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) to set the context (`this`) appropriately.

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute.call(this, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
```

Or you could rework the function definition to accept a context (you can't call it `this`, but you could call it `context`).

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(context, directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  ...
  for (var route in context.routes /*<--HERE*/) {
    console.log('www')
    if(route.id == context.filter){
      console.log('true')
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then in your `initMap`, you would pass `this` as the first argument:

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute(this, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
```

Comment: Are you saying I should do both (ie. the .call() and the context parameter)? If so, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: directionsService.route is not a function`. I am trying to print the context to the console but nothing appears.

Comment: It's one or the other. I would go with the second (passing `context` explicitly, don't use `call`). But you do need to pass `this` as the `context` parameter when you call it.

Comment: So far so good, but printing `context` to the console prints the tag with id `filterselect`. I need the fields contained within the `data()`

Comment: Got it by setting `this` to `thisContext` outside of the `onChangeHandler` and passing it to the function call. `this` within `onChangeHandler` seems to change to the tag with the id `filterselect`